# Why is the "Clinchers" objective not completing even though I scored goals in both semi-pro and pro difficulty?

Tags: fifa-23

[image: screenshot of "Clinchers" objective]

I scored several goals in semi-pro and pro in the same game, but the objective is still null.

So is there any other condition that I'm missing?

Comment: Stupid question... you also won those games, didn't you?

Comment: @pickerman no, it doesnt stupid. Yes, even more I scored 2 goals in extra time in squad (in coop). Maybe is bugged?

Comment: Have you tried playing alone or in rivals mode?

Comment: I tried alone also, Ill try rivals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bugged, only worked after resetting the game.